# Differential equations with missing variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y\cdot y'' + (y')^2 = 0$$

I'll make $V=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$, $y''=\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=V\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}y}$

$$\Rightarrow  yV\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}y}+V^2 = 0$$

What am I supposed to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v=\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$ so $y''=\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=v'v$

$y\cdot y'' + (y')^2 = 0$ so $yv'v+v^2=0$  then $yv'v=-v^2$ and $yv'=-v$

$\frac{v'}{v}=-\frac{1}{y}$  then $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=v=\frac{1}{y}$

and

$\frac{1}{2}y^2=x$

Comment: This is missing a lot of solutions. In particular, $y^2 = A(x-B)$ is a solution for suitable values of $A,B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $V = \dfrac{1}{2}y^2$. Then, $\dfrac{dV}{dt} = yy'$ and $\dfrac{d^2V}{dt^2} = yy''+(y')^2 = 0$

This gives you an easy differential equation to solve for $V$. Use that to get $y$.

Comment: Thank you, but I should solve it throught independent variable missing

Comment: What do you mean "throught independent variable missing"? This method gives you a simple differential equation to solve for $V$, which you can use to get $y$.

Answer (score 0):

From where you are, I'd factor.

$$v(yv'+v)=0$$

so either $v=0$ or $(yv)'=0$.  I think the easiest way to solve it from the start, though would be to recognize the left side as being the result of the product rule, reducing the equation to $(yy')'=0$